# Is there a way/hook to get notified when bigquery tables get updated?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am looking for someway where my code on compute engine needs to be notified when my bigquery table gets updated ? Similar to object change notification on google cloud storage ? If not any work around ? My bigquery tables get updated using Data transfer service.

Comment: You can star this request and maybe it will be implemented https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, BigQuery does not have any type of notification functionality. It's probably a worthwhile [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%20status:open) though.

Your best bet is to write a script, schedule it (e.g. a cron), and have it check the last modified timestamp for the table/dataset and fire off a notification when it detects a change/update.